# Выполнить функцию через 5 секунд после ее завершения node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет. Нужно каждый раз вызывать функцию через 5 секунд после ее завершения, setInterval() не подходит так как он вызывает функцию каждые пять секунд. Подскажите пожалуйста как это организовать?

Answer (score 1):

```js
void function() {
  function foo(i = 0) {
    console.log(i);
    i++
    if(i<3)setTimeout(() => {
      foo(i)
    }, 5e3);
  }
  foo()
}()
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: `if (i < 3) setTimeout(foo, 5000, i);`

Comment: А просто в return запихнуть setTimeout не сработает?

Comment: @Дмытрык При чем здесь `return`?

Comment: @igor, любопытно, а везде работает? как давно

Comment: @Igor, Это как более понятный вариант решения вопроса.  Я просто интересуюсь

Comment: @qwabra Not supported in IE9 and earlier, нужен polyfill

Comment: ага, давно) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```js
function repeat(count) {
  console.log('start:', new Date());
  for (let i=1; i<10000000000; i++); // какие-то долгие вычисления
  console.log('finish:', new Date());
  if (count < 5)
    setTimeout(repeat, 5000, ++count);
}

repeat(1);
```